# Proof that the inverse transpose conjugate is the transpose conjugate inverse

Tags: matrices, transpose, dagger-categories

I am given that $A^{-1,T} = A^{T,{-1}}$, and I have to prove that $A^{-1,\dagger} = A^{\dagger,{-1}}$. I tried representing the question as

$$A^{-1,{T*}} = A^{T*,{-1}}$$

$$A^{T,{-1*}} = A^{T*,{-1}}$$

but I still can't figure out how to prove that the complex conjugate can commute. Am I allowed to assume it can or do I need to be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

$AA^{-1}=I$

$A^{-1, \dagger}A^{\dagger} = I^{\dagger} = I$

It follows $A^{-1, \dagger}$ is the inverse of $A^{\dagger}$

ie $A^{\dagger, -1} = A^{-1, \dagger}$

Line 2 uses the property $(BC)^{\dagger} = C^{\dagger}B^{\dagger}$